# loopback updateAll function problems

Tags: loopbackjs

I have model called Item and I want to increase count of the Item

So I code:

```
Item.updateAll({name:'bar'},{count:'count'+1},function(err,items){

});
```

But unfortunately it didn't work.

I know that I can do it by

```
Item.findOne({name:'bar'},function(err,item){
    Item.updateAll({name:'bar'},{count:item.count+1},function(err,items){

    })
});
```

But it just like a fool.

Is there any beautiful way to increment count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer only works for the mongodb connector AFAIK because it uses the `$inc` operator.  You'll need to add `"allowExtendedOperators": true` to your dataSource, see [this issue](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mongodb/pull/70#issuecomment-70727370) for more info on that.

This will update the `count` attribute by 1

```
Item.updateAll({name:'bar'}, {'$inc': {count: 1}}, function(err, items) {
  console.log('updated', items);
});
```